# Group member editing to file *automatically* changes ownership, group, and permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, user-groups

I have a directory which I'm trying to set up such that members of a group all have rwx privileges.  Here is a subset of the directory and its permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myusrnm grpnm 21638 2015-04-22 14:14 correct
-rwxrwxr--  1 myusrnm grpnm 14403 2015-04-22 14:14 correct.c
```

Now, I change over to one of the users in the group, confirm he's in it:

```
myusrnm@server:~/grpdir$ sudo su hisusrnm
hisusrnm@server:/grpdir$ whoami
hisusrnm
hisusrnm@server:/grpdir$ groups
hisusrnm sshusers grpnm
```

And edit correct.c.  Now, in the other terminal, I check the directory and find:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myusrnm grpnm   21638 2015-04-22 14:14 correct
-rwxrwxr--  1 hisusrnm hisusrnm 14368 2015-04-22 14:23 correct.c
```

I just realized the same thing happens when I edit a file; its group automatically changes to `myusrnm`, and its permissions automatically change to 774.  Why is this happening?  How can I get group members to edit a file without changing its group, its ownership, and its permissions?  Is this default Linux behavior?  Or is my system behaving extra-special?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [SetGID](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-4883/secfile-69/index.html) on the parent folder. It will cause the group-owner to remain that of the parent folders.

you can [turn on SetGID](http://linuxg.net/how-to-set-the-setuid-and-setgid-bit-for-files-in-linux-and-unix/) with `chmod g+s folder/path` or put a 2 in the highest order position of the numeric pattern; eg: `chmod 2740 folder/path`. if its a new folder, you can just apply the ownership to the folder and new files will take on the folders group-owner, or on an existing folder, indicate the folder itself, but use the chmod -R switch to set the permission on all the existing children. if the children have existing owners you will need to set those as well

```
chown -R user:group /path/to/existing/dir
chmod -R 2640 /path/to/existing/dir
```

As for why your permissions are changing, check your `umask`. it sounds like it is set to `0003`. have you customized it? consider changing it to `0022`.

Comment: Thanks, Frank.  My umask is 0022 already, and the hisusrnm guy is already set to 0022 as well.

Comment: Okay, after having done this (Well, I wanted 774 permissions, so I used `chmod 2774`; was this correct?), when hisusrnm edits the file, the group and permissions do NOT change, but the ownership DOES.  Is this the expected behavior?  One more question, I've made permission changes where the permissions seem to be either -rwxrwxr--, or -rwxrwsr--.  What's up with the x vs s difference?

Comment: yes, 2774 is 774 + SetGID. Its my understanding that if a user has write access to a file, but not to the parent directory, the owner user will change to be the editing user. This is apparently due to the way that the edit is handled by the kernel, either as a in-place edit, or as a replacement. Is that the case in this scenario. you could try applying SetUID if you want to fix the user for all files in the dir, but beware SetUID changes the way executables run.

Comment: So, I'm leaning towards installing ACL.  I think that what we want to do here will be easiest with that, and there are few enough users on the system, especially when it comes to users that even know what permissions are, that it doesn't seem like it will cause any problems.